# Add new format to Angular date filter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datefilter

Is it possible to inject a new shorthand format into the Angular date filter?

For example, I can currently do this: `{{ myScope.timestamp | date: 'shortDate' }}`.

What I'd like to do is this: `{{ myScope.timestamp | date: 'paddedShortDate' }}`, which would force single-digit date parts to be padded with a leading `0`.

I realize I can create my own filter to do this for me—I'm more curious if existing filters are extensive in any manner.

Comment: Whelp, took a few edits and re-reading a few things, but I found a way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source code [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/filter/filters.js#L444), `DATE_FORMATS` is fetched from `$locale`. While I wouldn't recommend editing these (As `$locale.DATE_FORMATS` is a private API, and can change in the future), you should be able to do it via a run block:

```
app.run(['$locale', function($locale) {
    $locale.DATETIME_FORMATS.paddedShortDate = 'MM/dd/yy';
}]);
```

As you mentioned, you didn't want to create another filter, but that in my opinion would be the better way to go. A simple filter should work fine:

```
var MY_DATETIME_FILTERS = {
    'paddedShortDate': 'MM/dd/yy'
};

app.filter('myFormat', ['$filter', function($filter) {
    return function(format) {
        return $filter('date')(input, MY_DATETIME_FILTERS[format] || format);
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Small correction to answer for any future visitors to this page: `return function(input, format) { return $filter('date')(input, MY_DATETIME_FILTERS[format] || format); }`